# Run loop until condition is no longer found in R

Tags: r, loops, sorting

I am not new to R but still very much a novice and learning (so explanations are very welcome). I have a dataset (165000+ entries) of a pedigree which is completely scrambled.

My **goal**: ensure that no individuals have a birthdate before their parents. If that is the case then I want to change that birthdate into an NA (I will then later turn this into a blank myself). Below a similar sample to my dataset. (there are also individual with unknown birthdate)

```
m <- data.frame(id =  c(1 , 4, 7,11,15, 2, 3, 5,20,17, 6, 8,19,14,13, 9,12,10,16,18),
                dad = c(NA,NA,NA, 4, 4,NA,NA,NA,18,7 ,NA,NA,14,7 ,5 ,NA, 5, 3, 9, 7),
                mom = c(NA,NA,NA,2 ,8 ,NA,NA,NA,16,10,NA,NA,13, 6, 2,NA, 1, 1, 6,11),
                yr = c(1977,1976,1977,1981,1984,1975,1976,NA,1989,1985,1978,1978,1988,NA,
                       1982,1978,1982,1980,1984,1985))

m1 <- transform(m, bornbefore = yr <= yr[match(mom, id)] | yr <= yr[match(dad, id)])
m2 <- transform(m1, yr_new = ifelse(bornbefore == TRUE, NA, yr)
```

Running this code only once, still leaves me with some bornbefore == TRUE. So I was wondering if there was a way to use any of the loop functions to get this done (apply family, while loop etc.)? I get very lost in the loo[ functions so help is appreciated.

Also, I was wondering if it might help to sort the data so that parents are before the offspring in the dataset? simply using `m[order(m$yr),]` does not work because sometimes offspring have a wrong birthdate and are then put before parents.

Thanks for any help in advance and I hope my question is clear.

Comment: On the plus side you have test, bornbefore, of the quality of your data that might be useful in imputing birth dates of offspring if the relationship of {mother/father} -> kid can be deemed reliable, so maybe you want to impute rather than drive out these erroneous entries.  I guess I'm saying use bornbefore to index bad data and make a reasonable rule to change them that fits with pedigrees and mark them as imputed.

Comment: Conceptually, I wonder if what you are doing is sensible. The underlying theory seems to be that if you're born before your parents, your birthdate is wrong. But what if *they* were born before *their* parents? Then their birthdate should be NA too. So, which order do you want to apply this logic in?

Comment: @dash2 I understand what you are saying. The case of the aprents sometimes being born before their parents also occurs in my dataset. But I am using R to "clean up"my dataset and will then run it through a program that will calculate a lot of things for me (which would take me forever in R). One of the things it does, is estimate birthdate for individuals with unknown birthdates, based on their parents birthdate and those of their offspring. in terms of order, i think it would be to start from individuals in generation 1 (oldest generation) and then go down through the pedigree

Comment: that makes sense and if you know the generations that's a natural way to limit the size of the database joins you are performing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it should work. It uses a combination of base R and dplyr:

```
m <- data.frame(id =  c(1 , 4, 7,11,15, 2, 3, 5,20,17, 6, 8,19,14,13, 9,12,10,16,18),
                dad = c(NA,NA,NA, 4, 4,NA,NA,NA,18,7 ,NA,NA,14,7 ,5 ,NA, 5, 3, 9, 7),
                mom = c(NA,NA,NA,2 ,8 ,NA,NA,NA,16,10,NA,NA,13, 6, 2,NA, 1, 1, 6,11),
                yr = c(1977,1976,1977,1981,1984,1975,1976,NA,1989,1985,1978,1978,1988,NA,
                       1982,1978,1982,1980,1984,1985))

library(dplyr)

m <- m %>% rename(dad_id = dad,
                  mom_id = mom)


dad <- m[,c("id", "yr")]
dad <- dad %>% rename(dad_id = id,
                      dad_yr = yr)

mom <- m[,c("id", "yr")]
mom <- mom %>% rename(mom_id = id,
                      mom_yr = yr)

m_new <- m %>% 
  left_join(dad, by = "dad_id") %>%
  left_join(mom, by = "mom_id")

m_new$bornbefore <- ifelse((m_new$yr <= m_new$dad_yr | m_new$yr <= m_new$mom_yr), TRUE, FALSE)
m_new$yr <- ifelse(m_new$bornbefore == TRUE, NA, m_new$yr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Joins are the natural way to go:

```r
library(dplyr)

m_dad <- left_join(m, m, by = c("dad" = "id"))
m_dad <- mutate(m_dad, yr.x = ifelse(yr.x >= yr.y, yr.x, NA)) 
m[] <- m_dad[1:4] # a nice trick to keep column names from m

m_mom <- left_join(m, m, by = c("mom" = "id"))
m_mom <- mutate(m_mom, yr.x = ifelse(yr.x >= yr.y, yr.x, NA)) 
m[] <- m_mom[1:4]
```

Comment: Note: joins on big data could be slow. If you can split your database up into separate lineages somehow, that might help. Or it may be fast enough anyway. Or you could try data.table for a speedup.